# Rewrite code using sed (search & replace)

Tags: php, bash, shell, sed

I have hundreds of statements like this in a codebase:

```
if ($stmt->execute(array(/* parameters */))) {
    $att = $stmt->fetchAll(); /* or any other fetch method */
} else {
    throw new DatabaseException(__METHOD__.": failed");
}
```

Another variant, which does not fetch any data:

```
if (!$stmt->execute(array(/* parameters */))) {
    throw new DatabaseException("Error");
}
```

In both cases, the `if ...` and `throw ...` should be removed, i.e. the first snippet would be reduced to:

```
$stmt->execute(array(/* parameters */));
$att = $stmt->fetchAll(); /* or any other fetch method */
```

and the second:

```
$stmt->execute(array(/* parameters */));
```

Note:

- `array(/* parameters */)` may be missing if there are no
  parameters present.
- `$stmt` may have another name (like `$foo`).

*Background: Instead of a lot of custom code, I would like to have PDO throw an Exception when an error occurs. Currently it is set to silently ignore errors, which needs a lot of additional checks...*

Note: If this is too complex for `sed` or similiar tools, I will accept an answer which points to another tool that could help avoid rewriting all those statements by hand.

Comment: Ok so what efforts did you try for yourself?

Comment: I searched for similar problems (and solutions), but found no example which was as complex as mine. Also, as I'm not familiar with `sed` and similar tools, I'm unable to adapt existing answers to my problem as almost all of them only contain the solution with no further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$> cat codes.txt

if ($stmt->execute(array(/* parameters */))) {
  $att = $stmt->fetchAll(); /* or any other fetch method */
} else {
  throw new DatabaseException(__METHOD__.": failed");
}
if (!$stmt->execute(array(/* parameters */))) {
  throw new DatabaseException("Error");
}

$> perl -p0777e 's:(if \(\s*\!?\s*)(.*?)(\s*\)\s*\{\s*)((.*?)\s*\}\s*else\s*\{\s*)?throw .*?;\s*\}:$2;\n$5:g' codes.txt

$stmt->execute(array(/* parameters */));
$att = $stmt->fetchAll(); /* or any other fetch method */
$stmt->execute(array(/* parameters */));
```

---

1. This solution is only for non-nested `{}` codes.
2. For nested `{}`, it will be very difficult, and I do not think regexp could do. You'll need to write a sort of parser for that.

Comment: for nested {} a recursive regex (?R) or (?n) can be used but to be safe must exclude { within comments `/*{*/` string `"{"` or character `'{'`, note that your code will remove all if statements

Comment: @Mahuel: it removes `if` statements only when that statement has command `throw`.

Comment: Thanks! This should already be very close to what I need. I should be able to refine the regex to fit some more special cases. If only need to rewrite 10 statements by hand that's way better than rewriting 500 ;)